# TYPO3 - Output the image path via typoscript and database?

Tags: database, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.7.x

In my Database is the TYPO3 Media-Image-File:
header_image = 1

Table: tx_test

Field: header_image

How can i output the image link?
I think i need the IMG_RESOURCE and the RECORDS ?

But i dont now it works. My Test:

```
10 = FILES
10 {
    references {
        table = tx_test
        #uid.data = uid
        fieldName = header_image
    }
    renderObj = RECORDS
    renderObj {
        10 = IMG_RESOURCE
        10 {
            file {
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                import.data = file:current:publicUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

works perfect!

```
#Title
    testTitle = COA
    testTitle {

        # Titel
        10 = RECORDS
        10 {
            source = 1
            dontCheckPid = 1
            tables = tx_test
            conf {
                tx_test = TEXT
                tx_test {
                    field = title
                    crop = 80 | | 1
                    stripHtml = 1
                    htmlSpecialChars = 1
                }
            }
        }
        stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |<title>|</title>|
        stdWrap.insertData = 1
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: What is your target HTML output?

Comment: I use a other code for the title and discription, and this forks fine. but now i need this for the og:image meta-tag: <meta property="og:image" content=".....">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here the Solution:**

thanks to Paul Beck

image output with image-crop:

```
10 = FILES
10 {
    references {
        table = tx_ext_name
        uid.data = GP:tx_ext_action|tx_ext_controller
        fieldName = header_image
    }
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj {
        file {
            treatIdAsReference = 1
            import.data = file:current:uid
            width = 1200c
            height = 630c
        }
    }
}
```

or for the normal image-url:

```
10 = FILES
10 {
    references {
        table = tx_ext_name
        uid.data = GP:tx_ext_action|tx_ext_controller
        fieldName = header_image
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        data = file:current:publicUrl
    }
}
```

Comment: `GP:tx_ext_action|tx_ext_controller` stands for parameters given with the URL of the page. In most cases it won't be desired to display images directly based on the URL, a page can rather have many different mages and content including the images could also depend on further aspects than the page or any given URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want the URI to the Image, this should do the job.

```
10 = FILES
10 {
    references {
        table = tx_test
        # YOU NEED AN UID HERE!
        #uid.data = uid
        fieldName = header_image
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        data = file:current:publicUrl
    }
}
```

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version are you using? How do you provide the UID of the record (show us the Typoscript) and please provide us your TCA configuration for the field header_image.

Comment: TYPO3 8.7
i have all "items" in a TYPo3 BE SysFolder, but this is not a UID, this is a PID or?

Comment: You have to provide the UID of the record having the image in the field "header_image" - not the page where the record is saved.

Comment: mh, this is all the time a other UID :)
is the same as tx_news / news-articel´s now i use at the moment: uid.data = uid - But it dont work

Comment: Ok its no problem to make it dynamically. In which context you want to display the URI? If it is a kind of "Detailpage" of your record, get the UID from the GET vars.

Comment: the "Detailpage" its not all the time, the same id! But the data-info is on the template!

Answer (score 0):

Having read the discussion in the comments of another answer about the uid in the `FILES` element, I tried some possibilities and this one works, if the TypoScript is embedded in that one for a whole record, which is retrieved by the TypoScript Elements `CONTENT` or `RECORDS`. It gets the uid from the content element (here: tt_content) where its saved.

```
10 = FILES
10 {
    references {
        table = tt_content
        uid.field = uid
        fieldName = image
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        data = file:current:publicUrl
    }
}
```

So the whole TypoScript could look like this:

```
myContent = CONTENT
myContent {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        where = AND {#CType}="tx_mysitepackage_pi1"
        orderBy = sorting desc
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = FILES
        10 {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                uid.field = uid
                fieldName = image
            }
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                data = file:current:publicUrl
            }
        }
        20 = TEXT
        20.stdWrap {
            field = header
            noTrimWrap =  |<h1> | </h1>|
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this for `plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1` doesn't work currently due to a bug in TYPO3 v12.4 (I haven't tested or verified v10 or v11 concerning the bug): https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100849?issue_count=76